# Multiple blockers with first strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Scenario:

Player A attacks with a 6/6 creature.
Player B assigns TWO blockers to block the 6/6 creature, each is 3/3 with first strike.

Which of these happens?

1. B's first strike blockers deal their damage first, destroying A's larger creature before it deals any damage
2. Each blocker must take its turn blocking. So the first 3/3 blocker does first strike damage, then dies. Then the second blocker does first strike damage, and lives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The 6/6 will die, and the 3/3s won't take any damage.

---

In the first strike Combat Damage Step, both 3/3 deal three damage to the attacker. It is destroyed shortly after for having marked damage matching its toughness. The 6/6 won't be around in the normal damage Combat Damage Step to deal damage to the 3/3s, so they'll survive intact.

If the attacker was a 7/7, it would survive the first strike Combat Damage Step and a second Combat Damage Step would get created for the remaining creatures (the 7/7) to deal their damage (destroying the blockers).

Comment: So basically if two 3/3 creatures with first strike blocked one 6/6 creature without first strike then the 6/6 creature will die but the two 3/3 creatures would live?

Answer (score -9):

Previous answer in-correct

When the 6/6 attacks you declare two 3/3 first strike blockers on the one 6/6.

The 6/6's controller chooses blocking order (which one will block first and which will block second).

It would play out like this (6/6 attacks blocked by 1st 3/3 first strike, 6/6 is a 6/3 untill the end of turn first 3/3 is destroyed, then 6/6 attacks the 2nd 3/3 first strike and is destroyed by the 3/3 before it attacks it)

In short the 6/6 will die and you will lose one of your two 3/3's.

hope this helped.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong on all counts except that the attacker chooses how to order blockers.  It doesn't go 'first strike then normal combat per creature' - _all_ creatures with first strike damage deal their combat damage, and then _all_ creatures without first strike deal theirs. (See rule 510.5)  Furthermore, the 6/6 is _never_ a 6/3, despite what Duels of the Planeswalkers tells you - it's a 6/6 _with 3 damage on it_.  (This can matter for effects that check a creature's toughness)

Comment: It's called "damage assignment order" (not "blocking order") because it must be picked for each creature that deals combat damage. I didn't mention damage assignment order because it's irrelevant to the question. In fact, you have absolutely no choice in the presented scenario. First 3/3's order: 6/6. Second 3/3's order: 6/6.

Comment: @ikegami (Nitpicking: that order is chosen during the declare blockers step, well before creatures actually get to do combat damage - see rule 509.2.  While it is irrelevant to the question as given, the attacker _does_ still get the choice of how they want to order blockers.)

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki, Fine, there are no *meaningful* choices since the attacker doesn't get to do any damage. But true, a Lightning Bolt or Giant Growth could make it meaningful.